# Can edits be for copying and pasting comments underneath an answer into the answer?

Tags: support

**Update.** I'm not asking about changing anything in the original answer.

I ask by dint of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/265062/53934. My eyes aren't very good hence I don't want to fret about subscripts in the comments. To boot, comments can't be edited and I muffed some latex. I don't want to delete the comment which'd bungle the order.

I know browsers authorize you to change size, but I want to shirk magnifying all the text. I want to shirk this. I just want the font size in the comments to be bigger, not the question.

Hence can I make a suggested edit to copy and paste the exquisite comments?

Can someone please clarify if moderators can edit comments?

Comment: On my computer, if I do command-plus, all the text gets bigger. Maybe there's something similar on your computer. (This won't help with making corrections, but it should help with reading)

Comment: I would be very tempted to reject such an edit as "too radical", with the explanation that if the author wanted those details in the answer, those details would have been placed there. As @GerryMyerson says, there should be a way to zoom in on the page (thereby making the comments larger and easier to read).

Comment: I have often enough edited a question to add in comments by the OP (typically a newbie) clarifying their question, and would v likely accept a suggested edit in those circumstances. As for an answer, less likely, especially if the poster was a high rep user.